# How to listen for changes to platformBrightness in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, themes

I'm setting up a system where when the user changes the system theme to dark mode, it changes the theme and with Flutter, it works all well and good! However, when the user changes the system theme, the system navigation and status bar don't change their colors. I have code running on the home page inside the build method but that doesn't seem to do it. Here's the code inside the home page build method:

```dart
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Brightness sysBrightness = MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness;
    if (sysBrightness == Brightness.dark)
      Themes.setDarkSystemColors();
    else
      Themes.setLightSystemColors();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: CustomAppBar(title: "Home"),
      drawer: CustomDrawer(),
      body: SizedBox(),
    );
  }
}
```

Here's the code in the main app with `theme:` and `darkTheme:`:

```dart
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: routes,
      navigatorObservers: [_routeObserver],
      theme: Themes.lightTheme,
      darkTheme: Themes.darkTheme,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'School Life',
    );
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can do it in many ways:

- #### Using `didChangeDependencies`

  ```dart
  // This callback will be invoked every time the platform brightness changes.
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();

    // Get the brightness. 
    var brightness = MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness;
  }
  ```
- #### Using `WidgetsBindingObserver`

  ```dart
  class _MyPageState extends State<MyPage> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
    @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    }

    // This callback is invoked every time the platform brightness changes. 
    @override
    void didChangePlatformBrightness() {
      super.didChangePlatformBrightness();

      // Get the brightness.
      var brightness = View.of(context).platformDispatcher.platformBrightness;
    }

    @override
    void dispose() {
      WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
      super.dispose();
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) => Container();
  }
  ```
- #### Setting listener in `initState`

  ```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    var dispatcher = SchedulerBinding.instance.platformDispatcher;

    // This callback is called every time the brightness changes. 
    dispatcher.onPlatformBrightnessChanged = () {
      var brightness = dispatcher.platformBrightness;
    };
  }
  ```

Comment: Works great . But using this overrides the default method. After adding our custom `onPlatformBrightnessChanged` method, the theme does not change automatically. How do we also add the method to change the theme of the app?

Comment: window.onPlatformBrightnessChanged = () {
      WidgetsBinding.instance.handlePlatformBrightnessChanged();
      if (AppStorage.instance.themeMode == ThemeMode.system) {
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
          setState(() {});
        });
      }
    };

Answer (score 16):

[@CopsOnRoad answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61951046/438497) works perfectly, but it disabled auto reaction to platform brightness change in your widgets, to fix this problem use this :

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  var window = WidgetsBinding.instance!.window;
  window.onPlatformBrightnessChanged = () {
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.handlePlatformBrightnessChanged();
    // This callback is called every time the brightness changes.
    var brightness = window.platformBrightness;
  };
}
```

another way to handle this :

```dart
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addObserver(this);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangePlatformBrightness() {
    var brightness = Theme.of(context).brightness;
    super.didChangePlatformBrightness();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Listen to changes using (from WidgetsBinding)

```
void didChangePlatformBrightness()
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver/didChangePlatformBrightness.html

Answer (score 1):

[Feb 2022] - Working fine for me.

Use - ***final Brightness brightness = MediaQuery.platformBrightnessOf(context);***.

This will listen to theme changes. You can render differently based on this change.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Brightness brightness = MediaQuery.platformBrightnessOf(context);
    bool isDarkMode = brightness == Brightness.dark;
```

Later in the Widgets render based on ***isDarkMode***

For Example:

***AssetImage(isDarkMode ? darkBgImage : lightBgImage)***

```
Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage(isDarkMode ? darkBgImage : lightBgImage),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  colorFilter:
                      const ColorFilter.mode(Colors.black45, BlendMode.darken),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: If you read the question again, you will notice that the author has already tried your answer. So please suggest another solution.

Comment: Is the author trying to change the color of AppBar?

Comment: This code is ok

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 types of brightness:

- `MediaQueryData.platformBrightness`: "The current brightness mode of the host **platform**"
- `MediaQueryData.brightness`: "The **overall** theme brightness.". You probably want this.

If you have an in-app setting for users to configure the brightness differently/independently of the OS, `platformBrightness` doesn't work. You want your **app** brightness.

```dart
    // Doesn't always work, because platformBrightness is: "The current brightness mode of the host platform".
    final brightness_wrong_1 = MediaQuery.platformBrightnessOf(context);
    final brightness_wrong_2 = MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness;
    // If you use flutter hooks (doesn't work)
    final brightness_wrong_3 = usePlatformBrightness();
    // Works:
    final brightness = Theme.of(context).brightness;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [ThemeMode](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeMode-class.html) enum (since Flutter version 1.9, I think). So you can set `theme` to light and `darkTheme` to dark and `themeMode` (`ThemeMode.system` (default), `ThemeMode.light`, `ThemeMode.dark`) determines which theme will be used.

```
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData.light(),
  darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
  themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
)
```

However, I'm not sure if there is a way to listen for platformBrightness changes (`ThemeMode` also uses platformBrightness under the hood). You will need to rebuild `MaterialApp`...